# Ошибка при установке

Tags: база-данных, windows, oracle, windows-8

Версия Windows 8.1. При установке постоянно появляется вот такая ошибка:

[image]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, содержимое лога, на который есть ссылка в сообщении об ошибке

Comment: Я пытался его посмотреть, но почему-то он оказался пустым, что и затруднило мою проблему.

Comment: Ставите БД на виртуалку? Попробуйте perl стартануть, что скажет.